# Simple Pine-script code to chart a pair price of two equities (code included)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

So, I would like to monitor some pairs I trade on trading view and am completely new to coding and pine-script . I am actually learning python at this time but ventured off the beaten path to figure out this simple bit of pine script code .

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

// this is my pair
//objective is to plot a pair price of stock 1(bns_1) and stock 2(yelp_2) 
//pair price == stock 1 - (stock 2 * hedge ratio)

bns_1 = security("NYSE:BNS", "1", close)
yelp_1 = security("NYSE:YELP", "1", close)


hedge_ratio = bns_1/yelp_1

pair_price = bns_1-(yelp_1*hedge_ratio)

plot(pair_price)
```

So , It seems like the problem here is when I try to get pine script to use my "hedge_ratio" variable in the plot() parameter's. I have tried all sorts of ways to restructure the code to do the same thing but ask it in slightly differnt ways to no success.

using that code I can do the following succesfully :

```
plot(bns_1-yelp_2)
plot(bns_1*yelp_2)
```

....or I even manually entered the hedge_ratio as a float and it charted a perfect pair price(below) ...

```
plot(bns_1-yelp_2*1.88)
```

SO~ I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong when it comes to the hedge_ratio variable.

Any takers ? Your help would be VERY appreciated :)
Thanks in advance.

Here is todays BNS and YELP Values plugged in to show that the formula seems to work with a link that shows what the pair price should look like when I chart it in pine script that just has a manual hedge ratio inserted to make it work .

```
//Todays BNS and yelp value below: 

bns_1 = $44.40 
Yelp_1= $23.35

formula to plug in stock value's below 

pair_price = bns_1-(yelp_1*bns_1/yelp_1)
pair_price = 44.4-(23.35*44.4/23.35)
pair_price = 44.4-(23.35*1.9)
pair_price = 44.4-44.36
pair_price = 0.035
```

https://www.tradingview.com/chart/BNS/ddcMA52L-Good-statistical-arbitrage-to-justify-long-position-in-YELP/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there is a logic problem, not with the code.

Lets take a closer look:

```
hedge_ratio = bns_1/yelp_1
pair_price = bns_1-(yelp_1*hedge_ratio)
```

substitute `hedge_ratio`  in the `pair_price` formula:

```
pair_price = bns_1 - (yelp_1 * bns_1 / yelp_1) = bns_1 - bns_1 = 0
```

The result of the `pair_price` variable will always be 0.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I don't really understand ??

Comment: you multiply bns_1 by yelp_1 and then divide by yelp_1 = the result is bns_1. Then bns_1 - bns_1 = 0.

Comment: I am still having trouble writing the correct formula though . Was never good in math lol . Can you help please?

Comment: you are missing some precision points when you try to calc the hedge_ratio:  44.4/23.35 = 1.9014989293, not 1.9.

Comment: Ok, I now understand and realize where I am going wrong . I set the code to refresh every 1 candle and that creates an issue because I always resets to 0 . The actual input (without coding) on trading view works just fine for a pair price and the hedge ratio does not need adjustment . So, I actually do not need to code this it works just fine with trading views gui. All I need to do is manual calculate the hedge ratio (stock 1/stock 2) and then calculate stock 1 - stock 2*(hedge ratio) . This will provide a proper pair price , starting at 0 that automatically updates .

Comment: Just want to say thank you again , you really helped me , I spent a long time on that lol

Answer (score 0):

You can use equations such as TICKER1-HEDGE*TICKER2 to plot the pair price in TradingView. This strategy uses it in action: https://www.tradingview.com/script/EWWDwBoK-Bollinger-Pair-Trade/